# Continuity and Differentiability at end point of an interval

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

Let $ f(x) = x(\sqrt {x} + \sqrt{x+1})  $

The problem had asked to check continuity and Differentiability at $ x = 0 $

First of all I noticed that the Natural Domain of the function is non negative Real Numbers i.e zero is the least point of interval

Secondly I noted that $f(0)=0 $
And that the Right Hand Limit is also zero , implying that $f(x)$ is continuous at $0$.

My lecturer had told that to check Differentiability on the end point of an interval we need that the Right Hand Derivative must be finite . When I evaluate the  Right Hand Derivative it comes to be equal to $1$ (and hence finite, and therefore differentiable )
$$  \lim_{h\to 0} \frac {f(0+h) - f(0)}{h} (where  h>0) $$
Which evaluates to $$ \lim_{h\to 0} \frac {h(\sqrt {h} + \sqrt {1+h}) - 0}{h} , $$ the h cancels out and we are left with 1 .

But the problem book says that the function is not differentiable at $x=0$ as it not defined from the Left side . I am confused on which is correct ?

Comment: How did you calculate the right hand derivative to be equal to $1$? Can you write out the general calculations you made? (the mistake was likely somewhere in the calculations, so it might be useful for us to see them)

Comment: Please see the edit. I hope it is clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your calculations are correct, so this comes down to definitions. Usually, the definition of differentiability requires the function to be defined at some *neighborhood* of a point. This is not true for $x=0$. For example, the [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_of_real_functions_of_one_variable) talks about differential functions as something that exists for points in an *open* set on which $f$ is defined. There is no open set on which your function is defined that would include $0$, so the function is not differentiable at $0$.

This means that you have a slightly strange situation here where the function has a *derivative* at $0$, but is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: Thank you for answering ! Actually, the problem is from an exam and in the exact Question they didn't provide with open or closed interval that is, it was left for the students to consider . So why should I consider open interval instead of closed one as $0$ is also a point in interval ? Another question , is the definition which I wrote above tells you only about the value of derivative , not about Differentiability ?

Comment: @P8324R You should consider a closed interval. But in order for the function to be differentiable at $0$, the function should be defined on an open interval containing $0$, and therefore, the function is not differentiable.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying , I understood.

Comment: @P8324R Remember to accept the answer if it is what you needed.

Comment: Oh, sorry ! , I am new here , so I don't know what system is followed here .